# GitLab: partially public projects

Tags: permissions, project, public, gitlab

I'm just starting with gitlab 5.2, setting it up and configuring it.

I have seen that you can configure a project as public, and in that case all the users can clone the repo and see it in the public area of the web site.

You can also make projects non-public, and then just project members will be allowed to clone or see them in the web.

But I can't figure out how to get the behavior I need. I would like to have private projects (not accessible for anonymous users) but having all users in the platform as "reporters" of all the projects, by default.

What I want is every register user able to see every project, clone it, create issues, etc. Non registered users shouldn't be able to do that. Then, certain users or teams will have higher access to certain projects (master, developer...)

Is that possible?

I thought of creating a team called "everyone", where I add all the users and all the projects. First problem is that I need to keep in mind to add every new user to this team, and every new project to this team. But the main problem is that it seems to override project access for a user: if an user is granted as master in a project, and then I add this user as guest in the team "everyone", and I add this project to the team "everyone", the user becomes just guest for this project, deleting his previous master grant.

Any idea about how to solve this? Thanks for the support!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The desired functionality should exist in GitLab 5.2. See https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/3801 and http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3159951-allow-public-repositories for more details on the level of functionality that exists at this time.

Comment: This is basically the "public projects" I'm talking about... those public are accessible by everyone, even unregistered people, and visible in the public area of the website.


What I'm looking for is a partially public project, meaning, creating private projects but making then accessible to all registered users.

Comment: I think that the new "public projects" features from 5.2 is cool, but I'll suggest you another level of security, for example the "public for deploy project". In particular for example if I won't show the git url in the public page, but I want that the project is passwordless clonable from a machine where I put a deploy script like buildout. I'm not interested to give the possibility di anonimous users to see thw url and to see the project

Comment: Http://feedback.gitlab.com is the best place for suggestions.