# How do I configure GitLab to allow all users to share a group or the global namespace?

Tags: git, gitlab

I've successfully set up GitLab 5.2 on Ubuntu Server 12.04, but I'm having a bit of a problem with the default configuration - every user can create projects in his own "private group", just like github. What I'd like to have is a small company setup where everyone can keep their private repos, but also have a common group for shared (i.e. company) projects. What I'm asking is quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16734938/78928).

For example, is there a way to set it up so I can have a group called "${company name}", and allow all users with an account to create projects there and have access to all projects (in that group) as developers?

If this can't be done easily, I'd be satisfied with just allowing everyone access to a shared group (or even the global namespace) and adding people to projects manually.

Are any of these options possible at the moment, or do I simply need to wait for GitLab folks to implement features which will make this possible?

Comment: I would very much like to hear an explanation for the downvote here. *Edit*: In the sense of how can I improve this question..

Comment: not seeing the downvote, i only see a favorited

Comment: @bbodenmiller: Someone _fixed_ it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitLab has released version 6.0 which now [allows multiple users to be owners of a single group](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/5.4-to-6.0.md#teams). Therefore, the solution to this question is now natively supported by GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a company team (of users) for your company and then assign that team to each project you want them to have access to. As users are added to or removed from the company team they will be added to and removed from the assigned projects.

[image: Assign project to Team of users]

You may be interested in reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/15894795/1233435 to understand the difference between a team and a group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can do this, but this takes quite a bit of manual work, and still doesn't accomplish what I asked :( I want to enable users to use the same group for new projects. With teams, I can only assign everyone to _projects_, but every time someone creates a new project it will be created in their own (private) group, and then an administrator would need to move it to the shared group. I was hoping it's possible to make the global namespace (or a custom group) default for all users, in order to avoid admin actions.

Comment: Just because it is in their namespace doesn't mean it is private. If a team is assigned to a project in user namespace they can access it.

Comment: You may be interested in this feature request: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3942202-allow-groups-to-have-multiple-owners-so-multiple-

Comment: Hey wow, that feature request is exactly what I had in mind; I guess we have the same problem, don't we? :) I've registered and voted, hopefully we'll see it implemented some day.. So I guess you can turn your answer into "it can't be done with version N" so I can accept it. If we're lucky, you'll get to update the question some day with some good news.